# Stopping windows service from asp.net application on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

How can I stop windows service from asp.net application on windows 7 machine in such manner:

```
var sc = new ServiceController("TapiSrv", "localhost");
sc.Stop();
```

When I call `sc.Stop()` I get the following `Cannot open TapiSrv service on computer 'localhost'.`

**Update:**
I tried to use network ip instead and I got the same. I found out that I always can start but can't stop. I tried impersonation (WindowsImpersonationContext) but it didn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `localhost` with the current machine name.

Or you can do `Process.Start("net stop TapiSrv");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ServiceController()` class in ASP.NET application but you have to impersonate a user that have rights to manage services.

```
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController("PACSService");

        if (service != null)
        {
            try
            {
                switch(instruction)
                {
                    case SerwerRequest.Start:
                        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                        {
                            service.Start();
                            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        }
                        break;
                    case SerwerRequest.Stop:
                        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                        {
                            service.Stop();
                            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        }
                        break;
                    case SerwerRequest.Restart:
                        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                        {
                            service.Stop();
                            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));
                        }
                        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                        {
                            service.Start();
                            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return Json(new { status = 1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException exc)
            {
                return Json(new { status = -4 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { status = -99 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { status = -6 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```